# VueJs doesn't update when binding passed props to data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lifecycle, vue-component

I'm a beginner in vue. I was wondering why the lifecycle of vue doesn't trigger when the value updates.

```js
Vue.component('list-table', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ mydata }}
    </div>
  `,
  beforeUpdate () { console.log('before update') },
  updated () { console.log('updated') },
  data () {
    return {
      mydata: this.data
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    datum: [
      { f: 'John', l: 'Doe', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Jane', l: 'Doe', g: 'Female' },
      { f: 'John', l: 'Smith', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Jane', l: 'Smith', g: 'Female' },
      { f: 'Roy', l: 'Smith', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Reign', l: 'Smith', g: 'Female' }
    ],
    itemPerPage: 2,
    currentPage: 0
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList () {
      const startIdx = this.currentPage * this.itemPerPage
      const endIdx = startIdx + this.itemPerPage 
      return this.datum.slice(startIdx, endIdx)
    },
    totalPages () {
      return Math.ceil(this.datum.length / this.itemPerPage)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPage (num) {
      this.currentPage = num - 1
    }
  }
})
```

I know that the binding won't change because it was instantiated on passing only but if you see the `updated` function it won't trigger the log. Here's [a pen](http://codepen.io/mateeyow/pen/pPRaob) to check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing your component's local data to what is in the prop, but are not otherwise using the prop, so no updating ever happens. If you change the component to use `data` instead of `mydata`, updating happens.

If you want to make some change based on updated data, [use a `watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the data.

```js
Vue.component('list-table', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ data }}
    </div>
  `,
  beforeUpdate () { console.log('before update') },
  updated () { console.log('updated') },
  data () {
    return {
      mydata: this.data
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    datum: [
      { f: 'John', l: 'Doe', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Jane', l: 'Doe', g: 'Female' },
      { f: 'John', l: 'Smith', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Jane', l: 'Smith', g: 'Female' },
      { f: 'Roy', l: 'Smith', g: 'Male' },
      { f: 'Reign', l: 'Smith', g: 'Female' }
    ],
    itemPerPage: 2,
    currentPage: 0
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList () {
      const startIdx = this.currentPage * this.itemPerPage
      const endIdx = startIdx + this.itemPerPage 
      return this.datum.slice(startIdx, endIdx)
    },
    totalPages () {
      return Math.ceil(this.datum.length / this.itemPerPage)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPage (num) {
      this.currentPage = num - 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for='list in filteredList'>
        <td v-for='prop in list'>
          <list-table :data='prop' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <span v-for='page in totalPages'>
      <button @click='setPage(page)'>{{ page }}</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I already know that, but my main question is why is the `updated` lifecycle not triggering when passing the new value? There is actually a use case as to why I'm binding it to `mydata` instead of `data`

Comment: No updating is happening. The data you change has no effect on the DOM, so nothing is being updated. If you want to do something based on a change to data, use `watch`.

Comment: Ah, i see. So watch is really my only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to modify `mydata` to trigger the update.

You can do : `this.mydata.paramThatDoesntExist = true` inside `mounted ()`

```
mounted () {
  this.mydata.forceUpdate = true
}
```

That way, when the component is mounted, mydata is modified and the component is updated.